# Array bidimensional em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o array bidimensional

```
a = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[3,'e'],[3,'f'],[4,'g'],[4,'h']]
```

e quero separar as letras em outro array b de modo que fique assim:

```
[["a","b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]]
```

Onde o conteúdo cada índice do novo array(Ex: `["a", "b"]` corresponda ao primeio item do array a (`a[0][0]` e `a[1][0]`...etc), fiz isso pra tentar resolver a questão:

- primeiro criei o array bidimensional

  ```
  for i in (1..4)
    b[i] = Array.new
  end
  ```
- depois o código

  ```
  c = 0
  x = 0
  a.each do |k|
    if  k[0] == a[x+1][0]
      b[k[0]][c] = k[1]
      c += 1
      x += 1
    else      
      b[k[0]][c] = k[1]
      c = 0
    end
  end
  ```

O problema é o índice `'c'` que a partir do terceiro índice do array b, está indo pro índice 2 e o próximo o 4 em progressão saindo assim...

```
[nil, ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], [nil, nil, "e", "f"], [nil, nil, nil, nil, "g", "h"]]
```

Acho que pode ser uma coisa simples nesse índice, mas já estou misturando as coisas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente usar menos manipulação de índices, que tornam o código confuso. Geralmente o Ruby permite isso.

O código abaixo cria elementos em `b` para cada índice encontrado nos elementos de `a`. Então, adiciona a esse elemento em `b` os elementos encontrados em `a` para aquele índice.

```
a = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[3,'e'],[3,'f'],[4,'g'],[4,'h']] 
b = Array.new
a.each do |k|
  b[k[0]] ||= Array.new
  b[k[0]] << k[1]
end
b # => [nil, ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]]
```

Comment: Nossa, muito bom GuiGS, solução prática d+, muito obrigado. Para chegar a um lugar temos vários caminhos, mas eu estava tentando um caminho difícil, por isso não chegava, estou aprendendo ruby e isso me deixa mais apaixonado ainda por essa linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

O bonito de ruby é que quase todos esses tipos de processamentos podem ser escritos em uma linha, sem usar loops diretamente. É como trabalhar com uma linguagem funcional. Observe:

```
a = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[3,'e'],[3,'f'],[4,'g'],[4,'h']]
result = a.inject([]) {|r, k| r[k[0]] ||= []; r[k[0]] << k[1]; r }
```

*Inject* serve para construir um valor iterativamente. Você passa o valor como argumento e, a cada iteração, recebe o valor atual e um argumento e deve retornar o próximo valor. Um pouco mais explicado:

```
result = a.inject([]) do |temp, element|
   index, value = element
   temp[index] ||= []
   temp[index] << value
   temp
end
```

Pode usar o `inject!` também para aplicar a modificação *inplace*.

Comment: Não é a toa que amo essa linguagem, várias maneiras de se chegar a um resultado, essa então do inject é ninja.